# Failed to load plugin import: 'eslint-plugin-import'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm new to react. I'm following the tutorial steps installing node. However, when I run `npm start`, errors keep show up.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module build failed: Error: Failed to load plugin import: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-import'
Referenced from: 
at Array.forEach (native)
at Array.reduceRight (native)
```

Also, I tried to install 'eslint-plugin-import', but in vain...

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import -g

npm WARN eslint-plugin-import@2.7.0 requires a peer of eslint@2.x - 4.x but none was installed.

+ eslint-plugin-import@2.7.0
```

System info

```
eslint --version
v4.2.0

npm -v
5.2.0

npm list -g | grep eslint
├─┬ eslint@4.2.0
│ ├─┬ eslint-scope@3.7.1
├─┬ eslint-plugin-import@2.7.0
│ ├─┬ eslint-import-resolver-node@0.3.1
│ ├─┬ eslint-module-utils@2.1.1
├─┬ eslint-plugin-react@7.1.0
```

Comment: can you pls post your .eslintrc and webpack.config files

Comment: isntalling 'esling-plugin-import' solved the error mentioned in the questoin. However, it keeps failing at loading elint modules namely eslint-plugin-flowtype, eslint-plugin-jsx-ally....

Comment: Yep, it seems that i still need to install `eslint-plugin-flowtype` and `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The issue is resolved for me after installing the following in a row:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-flowtype eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-react
```

Have you tried installing `eslint` locally, like

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import --save-dev
```

?

**Edit -Solution:**

Instead of installing `eslint` packages one after another, the problem can be alleviated by

```
npm install react-scripts
```

as react-scripts is taking care of `webpack`, `babel` and `eslint` and the dependencies thereof.

This may avoid conflicts, as in your case.

Answer (score 9):

Run today in the same problem. Had upgraded ESLint 5.16 to 6.6.0 and had been using the vue-eslint-plugin 5.2.3. 
Had to install this packages:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import --save-dev
npm install eslint-plugin-node --save-dev
npm install eslint-plugin-promise --save-dev
npm install eslint-plugin-standard --save-dev
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
npm install -g eslint
```

then

```
eslint --init
```

Comment: After the messages from `eslint --init`, I tried to reinstall the packages it mentionned, globally since it installed it locally. There still was a missing dependency for `eslint-plugin-import` which I added. I ended to this, which works (at least for me): `npm -g install eslint eslint-plugin-node eslint-plugin-standard eslint-plugin-promise eslint-config-standard eslint-plugin-import`

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this while running `create-react-app` after a successful `npm install`. Bringing down the npm version from v5.2 to v4.6.1 fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use this

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import --save-dev
npm i eslint-plugin-jasmine --save-dev
npm i eslint-plugin-sonarjs --save-dev
npm i eslint-plugin-switch-case --save-dev
npm i eslint-plugin-unicorn --save-dev
npm i @angular-eslint/eslint-plugin --save-dev
```

then Hit **ng lint**